# How do you delete entries from a frontend form?

Tags: form, entry

[Part 2 of a 3 part question:](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/how-do-you-delete-assets-entries-from-a-frontend-form/2029#2029)

I am creating a proof of concept for a client in Craft where the client's customers can manage projects from the frontend of a Craft install.

I have a frontend form working correctly for creating a new project via it's own section. However the missing piece to the puzzle for full management is being able to delete an entry in the projects channel.

How do you delete entries from a front end form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's going to be virtually identical to [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2029/57), with the exception that you're posting to the 'entries/deleteEntry' controller action instead of 'assets/deleteFile' and you're posting the 'entryId' and the 'locale' of the entry you want to delete, instead of 'fileId'.

Note that this requires a logged in user with necessary delete entry permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Brad!! I figured as much and almost considered answering my own question but I wasn't sure what the action url was and how best to word it.